# Can't extract certain text using xpath which gets broken because of namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to extract text out of some html elements using xpath but can't figure out how to form one. The key thing here is to make use of this `ga:type="Comment"` within the xpath.

Html elements:

```
<div ga:type="Comment" class="store" dir="auto">This text should be parsed.</div>
```

My try so far:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

elements = """
<div ga:type="Comment" class="store" dir="auto">This text should be parsed.</div>
"""

root = fromstring(elements)
item = root.xpath("//*[@ga:type='Comment']")[0].text
print(item)
```

Output I wanna get:

```
This text should be parsed.
```

Upon execution I get thie following error:

```
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
```

***How can I create an xpath containing this portion `ga:type="Comment"` within it and still has the capability to parse the text?***